# Execution enters IF loop, even if the condition is not satisfied

Tags: apex, if

```
if(User.FirstName != NULL && User.MiddleName != NULL && User.LastName != NULL) {

User usr = [SELECT FirstName,MiddleName,LastName FROM User WHERE 
                                       id=:userinfo.getuserid()];

System.debug('from if   FirstName  '+usr.FirstName);
System.debug('from if   MiddleName  '+usr.MiddleName);
System.debug('from if   LastName  '+usr.LastName);
}
```

Even, if FirstName & MiddleName are NULL, execution enters if loop. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please provide more context code. Do you have a variable named `User`?

Comment: I assume that User.FirstName automatically takes in current users FirstName. so i haven't declared it prior in my code. Is this right ??

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce has a global variable `$User`, there is no equivalent in apex.

In your code, `Object.FieldName` will return API name of field on the object with type `Schema.SObjectType`, you have to query User in an Object or list before the IF loop and use that for comparison.

Comment: Query approach worked. Thanks.